# Can we implement a custom ambari actions for upload/download purpose

Tags: ambari

Right now, we are using ambari to manager some custom serveices. we have followed the rules,like "add custom service/stacks" in ambari. we also read the info: "how to add custom actions" beside the routined life cycle actions, such as: "install, configure, start and stop"
However, our design need some special actions, for examples, Dowloading log/thread dumps from the server, or upload special key files to use in ssh/key auth. Have seached the web many days ,but find no clues.
Is it possible to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@stdanley

It sounds like some of the functionality you are describing could be done with a custom Ambari View.   For example, the hdfs/files view allows uploading files to hdfs.  You should investigate Ambari Views.  The Smartsense view would be good one to take a look at as an example.

It would be also possible to create a custom service which provides a UI on top of ambari.  You can then build the functionality you are looking for in the custom service's UI.  Those actions would be outside of the scope of ambari UI, in other words, not found in ambari drop downs, tabs, etc.

It is possible to add some custom functions into ambari service Action menus. But you may find those are simple interaction triggers, not feature ads.

Comment: Hi, DS , I also checked the view implements. We  may implement a custom view, but have no clue on how to link the service action, perhaps by using quick link, not custom actions